# Is there a way to have my mouse operate on 2 different monitors/computers at the same exact time?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse, multiple-computers

I’d like to know if there’s a way I can perfectly sync (or close enough at least) my mouse on 2 different computers/monitors (preferably computers) at once. Essentially I want to mirror my mouse on 2 different monitors at once. I have 2 computers and would like to be able to just have the mouse be able to operate on both at the same time without needing to use a switch. If worst comes to worst though I can hook up both monitors to one. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish? It sounds like you want to give a presentation of some sort, where one screen sees what happens on the other screen? You can of course mirror a screen so the desktop is displayed to 2 monitors at the same time. For remote control of 2 pc's, if it does not have to happen at the same time, there are also plenty of options available.

Comment: Is your mouse USB or PS2?

Comment: My mouse is USB

Answer (score 0):

A mouse will only talk to one device (normally a computer). Either wired (so then obvious) or wireless and paired with a specific device. A device with same setup and a different mouse will have the different mouse paired to the second device.

So given the above, there is no way for one mouse to appear on two different devices and monitors. The mouse is only keyed to one device.

A device with two monitors on one card / dock is different as that is one device and the mouse on one computer will deal with both monitors on one device.

However that kind of situation only allow one mouse movement at one time on one device.  Only a mirrored monitor (laptop plus mirrored external) would have the appearance of one mouse on two screens.

Comment: Is there any adapters/software that could help me accomplish this at all? Or is it literally technologically impossible?

Comment: I have not seen (hundreds of customer computers) any kind of adapter that will allow one mouse to manage different computers. I do not think this would be feasible.

Comment: There is software where you can control 2 pc's as if they were one with a seamless border where the computers are not physically connected other than network, but even then, the mouse movement only happens on one pc at a time.

Comment: https://youtu.be/VtjO3CLAIsg At the 2 minute mark in this video it does exactly what I want if that shows it better. Is there a way to accomplish this through software or is this a one of a kind hardware sort of thing?